# Why is my AJAX form posting mutliple times from my partial view in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am posting form data to my controller using AJAX, the form is located in a partial view which is called and displayed in a modal.  When first submit the form to update my data it works fine, then if I post it again I notice in the console log that it posts the data twice, if I post it again, it posts three times, and so on.  The only way to prevent that behavior is to refresh the page.

Here is the code for my partial view.

```
@model UserView
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-custom-view" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-custom-view" aria-modal="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg modal-notify modal-primary" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">             
            <form id="ModalFormEditCustomView" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Id" hidden readonly />
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="md-form form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ViewName">View Name</label>
                                <input type="text" required class="form-control" asp-for="ViewName" />
                            </div>
                        </div>                           
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <button type="button" data-save="edit-view" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light">Update</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div><!--/modal-footer-->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My function that posts the data.  Please note, `placeholderElement` is a div that is the modal window.

```
placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-save="edit-view"]', function (event) {
    //Prevent the standard behaviour
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    var dataToSend = form.serialize();       

    $.post(actionUrl , dataToSend).done(function (data) {
        var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
        placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);
        placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EditCustomView(UserView model) {
    ... update code goes here
    return Json(model);
}
```

This is the button that opens the modal with the form in it.

```
<button data-view-id='#=Id#' onclick='editViewModal(this, event)' data-area='Home' data-context='Position' data-toggle='ajax-modal' data-target='#edit-custom-view' data-action='EditCustomView' data-url='/Home/EditViewModal/'>Button</button>
```

And finally, the code that opens the modal and fetches the partial view.

```
public IActionResult EditViewModal(int id) 
{
    string partial = "_EditCustomView";
    UserView userView = _userViewService.GetUserView(id);        
    return PartialView(partial, userView);
}
```

So, when I click on submit, the ajax function is triggered to submit the data, and the modal closes.  If I edit the same item again without refreshing the page, the form gets submitted twice and so on, adding an additional post-event each time.  My question is, why?  I can't see any reason as to why it would do this.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is placeholderElement set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this script located? If it is inside of the partial that is what is causing the issue for you. Every time the partial is pulled in an extra event is attached to the element.

This would cause the behavior that you are describing.

Comment: Thanks for this, the script was indeed located in the partial view

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem since the code you provided is not complete. Maybe you can show us the `placeholderElement` and the scripts of `editViewModal(this, event)` function in the button click event.

Besides, in your case, we can call and display the a modal in the following way.

Here is a work demo:

**Model:**

```
public class UserView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
@model UserView

<div class="modal fade" id="edit-custom-view" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-custom-view" aria-modal="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg modal-notify modal-primary" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="ModalFormEditCustomView" data-action="/Home/EditCustomView" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Id" hidden readonly />
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="md-form form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ViewName">View Name</label>
                                <input type="text" required class="form-control" asp-for="ViewName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Address">Address</label>
                                <input type="text" required class="form-control" asp-for="Address" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Tel">Tel</label>
                                <input type="text" required class="form-control" asp-for="Tel" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <button type="button" data-save="edit-view" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light">Update</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div><!--/modal-footer-->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit View:**

```
@model UserView

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ViewName" class="control-label"></label> :
            <input asp-for="ViewName" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Address" class="control-label"></label> :
            <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Tel" class="control-label"></label> :
            <input asp-for="Tel" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="btn" value="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="placeholderElement">

</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>

        $(".btn.btn-primary").on("click", function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "/Home/EditViewModal?id=" + id,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#placeholderElement").html(result);
                    $("#edit-custom-view").modal('show');
                }
            });
        })
        $("#placeholderElement").on('click', '[data-save="edit-view"]', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
            var actionUrl = form.data('action');
            var dataToSend = form.serialize();
            $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {
                $("#placeholderElement").find('.modal').modal('hide');
                $("#ViewName").val(data.viewName);
                $("#Address").val(data.address);
                $("#Tel").val(data.tel);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Edit()
{
    var model = _db.UserViews.Find(1);
    return View(model);
}

public IActionResult EditViewModal(int id)
{
    string partial = "_EditCustomView";
    var userView = _db.UserViews.Find(id);
    return PartialView(partial, userView);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EditCustomView(UserView model)
{
    var model1 = _db.UserViews.Find(model.Id);
    model1.ViewName = model.ViewName;
    model1.Address = model.Address;
    model1.Tel = model.Tel;
    _db.Update(model1);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(model1);
}
```

**[image: Result:]**

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to produce this and help with the problem.  It turns out it was the script sitting inside the partial view that was causing the problem.